# "Taking summers off" and the impact on tenure decisions

Tags: tenure-track, working-time, work-life-balance, assistant-professor

Assume there is a young tenure-track professor on a 9-month salary who is a good instructor and manages to get research published at an appropriate pace during the school year for tenure consideration. Could the professor's decision on how he/she spends his/her 3 months each summer affect his/her tenure decision? Specifically, if the professor chose to do something unrelated to teaching summer courses or doing research.

I'll propose two examples:

1. Spend the summers working a completely unrelated (perhaps lower-level) job just to mix things up or out of necessity or delight. Let's say as a cruise-ship tour guide or as a laborer (e.g., painter, landscaper, farmer, mechanic, etc.)
2. Spend the summer vacationing with family / kids.

If the individual got the work required for tenure completed during the 9-months of the school year, they could do whatever they want the other 3 months (since they are *off* contract) without repercussions, right?

Comment: **This is an excellent question for your department chair.**  In principle, it shouldn't matter, but in practice, it depends on your department's culture.

Comment: @JeffE the question has only one, rather obvious, correct answer (see my answer), so in that sense I actually don't think this is an excellent question for OP's department chair. If the chair is not entirely clueless he/she will give the obvious official answer since anything else would be exposing the university, and maybe him/her personally, to a big liability; and if he/she _is_ entirely clueless, you shouldn't trust what they are saying anyway. So either way by asking them I don't see that you'd gain any useful information, and you may in fact get entirely wrong and misleading information.

Comment: @DanRomik: Really? I think it's perfectly plausible that a department chair could say something like "Officially, it's irrelevant.  Off the record, I have a sense that it might affect the votes of certain faculty members.  There was a previous case..."

Comment: "If the individual got the work required for tenure completed during the 9-months of the school year, they could do whatever they want the other 3 months (since they are off contract) without repercussions, right?"  This seems to me like a great example of a [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) statement.

Comment: @Dan Romik: I agree with the others. This is very plausible, especially at an R1 university (though you likely won't have profs at an R1 attempting to take *any* time away from their work :p...). I think a tenure committee would look at that pattern of work behavior and question your work ethic or dedication to being an effective tenured professor in the long run.

Comment: theforestecologist, plausible? Maybe, but this is pure speculation, and as I said in my answer, you're essentially speculating about people's thoughts about illegal discrimination, so neither I nor anyone else can give anything approaching an authoritative answer. If you feel comfortable speculating about this, go ahead; I don't. Also, part of what makes it difficult to answer is that as @NateEldredge commented, this is pretty near to being a vacuous question: the sample size, if there is even a sample, would be vanishingly small.

Comment: I deleted my answer, since based on @NateEldredge's comments it looks like a key premise I had assumed may be incorrect, which potentially undermines the validity of the entire answer. Sorry!

Comment: Could you explain why you're asking, please?  Is it that you are fantasizing about getting a tenure track job, and are hoping you can spend your summer snorkeling at the Great Barrier Reef?  That you are wondering how the heck the guy down the hall from you thinks he stands a chance of getting tenure if he spends his summer building himself a house out of straw and clay?  Something else entirely?

Comment: I second JeffE's comment.  There are some departments where nobody will even notice whether you're in town over the summer, because no one else is in their offices either, and as long as you get work done nobody will know or care exactly when you did it.  There are other departments where every closed office door will raise eyebrows, no matter how productive you are.

Comment: The 9-month contract issue is one of many thing that highlight how a research-oriented professor position is in an ambiguous middle ground between a "job" and a "hobby club".  It is easier to understand the conventions if you think of it as a little bit of both.

Comment: Something that I haven't seen any answers comment on--if you are advising graduate students, they may not want or be able to take the summer off.

Comment: I would like to know why you didn't like the new title

Comment: It was gramatically incorrect!

Answer (score 23):

This is *really* dependent on your department culture.

Officially (at least for all the tenure systems I've participated in), tenure decisions are based on the quality, reputation, and impact of the candidate's research (and to a lesser extent, teaching and service), and their potential for future intellectual leadership and international stature.  (Woo, that's a mouthful.)  In particular, the decision is based on **what the candidate has actually accomplished**.

Are they publishing high-quality work in high-visibility venues?  Is their work highly regarded in the research community (as described in the letters)?  Do they have a solid track record of external funding?  Do they have a solid track record of successful graduate student advising?  Have they accumulated other indicators of respect within their research community: awards, plenary talks, invitations to program committees/editorial boards, well-placed and successful students?  Do they have other evidence of research impact: open-source software, community-standard data sets, or patents?

If this case is strong on these merits, then the day-to-day work habits of the candidate shouldn't matter, and usually don't.  In particular, the reference letters, which are by far the most important component of the case, will be written by people who are probably completely unaware that the candidate disappears to a fishing lodge in the Adirondacks every summer.  There have been multiple successful tenure cases in my department where the candidate essentially vanished every summer.

More strongly: If their research case is strong, then what assistant professors do during the months the university is not paying them is really none of the promotion committee's business.  I work in a field where a three-month vacation in the Adirondacks (with a sufficient supply of pens and paper and reliable wifi) would be **amazing** for my research productivity.

Nevertheless, faculty are apes; we do apey things.  **Every department and every field has its own cultural norms, and assistant professors *must* be aware of and sensitive to those norms.**  Some departments have a shared belief—which may even be correct in their field—that the research required for a successful tenure case requires being physically present and visibly productive 24 hours a day, seven days a week, 52 weeks a year.  Others won't even *notice* when you're in the office being productive, because they all keep their office doors closed, or they work at home, or in coffee shops, or in a shack in in the Adirondacks.  Others have a de facto list of accomplishments that are necessary, sufficient, or both. (NSF CAREER? NIH R1? Three papers in *Science*? H-index above 50? IEEE Fellow? Letters from five Nobel laureates?)

Whether or not tenure decisions *should* depend on these local expectations is utterly immaterial.  They do.  Either you meet them, or you find a job somewhere else.  And the *only* way to understand what these expectations are in your department is to ask directly, and to insist on regular mentorship and feedback from senior faculty.

Comment: There's a lot of people who would be more productive with their research taking that time off and coming back refreshed. It's called the "work hard, play hard" mentality. (Or if you're like me, it would be the "work hard, laze around when you're not working "mentality...)

Comment: @corsiKa: of course - it is vital not to get burned out, and many of the best researchers take plenty of personal time for family, hobbies, and vacations. But they don't tend to do that for the entire summer, which seems to be the subject of this question.

Answer (score 9):

To answer your question literally, if the professor outputs research at a reasonable pace during the academic year, then *flatlines during the summer*, then no, they are not on track for tenure.

Perhaps you meant to ask if they are stellar and overperform during the year. This really raises the question of why they are not at a more prestigious university then, and if they are, I'm really curious which of the 7 or so people in the world capable of overperforming by a couple standard deviations at an R1 school you're talking about.

All-in-all you are asking something that misunderstands what this period of life is like. Being tenure-track but not tenured is one of several extremely demanding periods in an academic's life. "Demanding" and "triple the vacation of a typical industry job" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: "This really raises the question of why they are not at a more prestigious university then".  Maybe because they want to take the summer off?

Comment: @dan1111 Someone who can over-perform at research is unlikely to have more time available by working somewhere where they will have less time available for research.

Comment: @JessicaB, a high-performing academic can often extract lots of concessions in return for staying at a lower-tier institution.  It makes sense as a career path if they want a lower-pressure job.

Comment: [citation needed]  This answer may be true in your department, but it is _demonstrably_ not true in mine.

Comment: @JeffE post an answer then?

Comment: @dan1111 I actually thought about that and while I wasn't able to logically rule it out it still sounds odd. It seems working the full year to get tenure is a better strategy than figuring you'll probably get tenure at current output. I'm not sure if anyone really has this outlook. I'd like to hear an answer from someone who does and felt my answer, since it does represent the state of the world to my best understanding, should be posted in the meantime.

Comment: @djechlin, my point is simply that some people have priorities other than their career and therefore don't put 100% effort into their job.  This might not be the best strategy for their career, but it might be the best strategy for achieving their goals in other areas.  I'm sure you are generally right that working 12 months is the best strategy for getting tenure, but I'm equally sure that some people end up with tenure without doing this.

Comment: There is a significant difference between "You won't get tenure if you don't work 12 months a year" (which is what your answer says) and "Your chances for tenure are better if you work 12 months a year."  If you mean the latter, then you should change your answer to _actually say that_.

Comment: @JeffE no, I claimed you won't get tenure if you work 9 months a year. Was this unclear?

Comment: Sigh. Let me try again. There is a significant difference between "You won't get tenure if you work 9 months a year" (which is what your answer says) and "Your chances for tenure are better if you work more than 9 months a year." If you mean the latter, then you should change your answer to actually say that.

Answer (score 8):

Everyone has their own opinion about the purpose or benefits of 9-month contracts (which is not to say the history of how they developed). It appears [to some extent](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31236/number-of-months-a-year-that-faculty-get-paid-in-uk-and-australia/31239#31239) that these contracts are unique to the United States in any case.

Other answers point out the importance of knowing the local culture of your department. I want to point out a few commonly-held beliefs about the role of summer time for research-intensive faculty, which are good to know when you try to assess that culture. These are beliefs that a significant number of research active faculty will have.

- A benefit of 9-month contracts is to allow you time (mostly) unencumbered by teaching and service to work on your research. Of course, you might be able to do this from a cabin in Alaska, but it is not "time away from research" strictly speaking.
- For researchers who need to travel, e.g. those studying the art, history or cultures of other countries, the summer is a time to spend a few months in the country they study, going to libraries and museums to do the groundwork for research. Similarly, those who need to do field work (ecology, geology, archaeology, ...) can use the summer months to gather data.
- A third benefit, in some disciplines, is to allow you to take salary from other discipline-related work during the summer, e.g. grant support in STEM fields or consulting work in business or engineering.   For example, many grant agencies will not allow a researcher to take salary from a grant while also drawing salary from the university. The 9-month contract circumvents this by not paying university salary during the summer.

So, from a certain viewpoint, the benefit of 9-month contracts is that they allow you to do *more* tenure-related work over the summer, not less.  It would be a mistake to think that many research-intensive universities have a standard that makes it easy for the average tenure-track faculty member to earn tenure while not using the summer in any way for research.

At these schools, the "appropriate pace" for research already assumes that faculty are working on research over the summer, which is why some other answers seem incredulous at the idea that a faculty member would be publishing at "appropriate pace" while also working as a waiter on a cruise ship all summer.

The situation can be very different in departments where research is not very important for tenure. These departments may have a local culture of doing some service over the summer (or not), but in my experience they generally do have more of a culture of taking the summer off. This is particularly noticeable in "transitioning" departments, where older faculty had fewer research expectations, and so developed a culture of "taking off" the summer, while younger faculty are required to do more research for tenure and do not have that luxury.